How many homomorphisms $C_9 \rightarrow S_4$ are there?
How many homomorphisms $C_9 \rightarrow S_4$ are there?
[I want to use the fact that the order of $\phi(g)$ divides the order of $g$ and somehow work from there (I also know that if $\phi$ is surjective and $S_4$ has a element of order $n$ then $C_9$ must have an element of order $n$).
I know that $C_9$ has elements of order 1,3 and 9, but $S_4$ has elements order 1,2,3,4. I’m not sure how to piece this together or what other info I need.]

@DietrichBurde yes I think so, just to check is the equivalent answer 9? (if not I’m still confused).

Hint. Each   homomorphism  is determined by the image of a generator. What permutations might those images be?
(Surjective is impossible: the codomain is larger than the domain.)

The generator has to go to a element of order 3, and there’s 8 such elements, then the trivial one. So would that be 9 total? (If I’m understanding correctly)

@Anon314159 Yes.
